# Can't rotate object from other place that isn't origin point

Tags: c++, opengl, math, 3d, glm-math

I know that the supposed way to make this as simple as possible is to use:

```
glTranslate(a,b,c);
glRotate(...);
glTranslate(-a,-b,-c);
```

But in this case I'm using buffers to make things more clear and fast, the thing is that I'm doing the equivalent which is:

```
iMat4x4 tempModel;
iMat4x4 tempModel2;


tempModel = math::translate(tempModel, iVec3(0.5f * size.x, 0.5f * size.y, 0.0f));
model[3].z = model[3].w = 0;
model[3] = model[3] + tempModel[3];

model = math::rotate(model, rotation, iVec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

tempModel2 = math::translate(tempModel2, iVec3(-0.5f * size.x, -0.5f * size.y, 0.0f));
model[3].z = model[3].w = 0;
model[3] = model[3] + tempModel2[3];
```

But still, when I do something like `object->rotation = sin(Time::WorldTime)` I get the object rotating from the upper left corner.

Also, what is supposed to be the objective of moving the object to the origin before rotating, the rotation matrix has no effect wether I change it, and the 4th Column of the matrix is not multiplied in any way with the rotation matrix, just placed where it was before...

Comment: Adding the translational component is **not** equivalent to multiplying by the corresponding translation matrix, the latter being the correct way.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I don't get it. What should be the intended operation then? (without affecting the objects current position) multiplying and then dividing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the translational matrix's elements is **not** equivalent to multiplying by the corresponding translation matrix, the latter being the correct way to apply the translation.

---

*Explanation*

[Rotation matrix `R`, translation offset `t` - matrix `T`, model point `p`.]

Directly adding the translation matrix `T` is equivalent to *pre-multiplying* by it, which means the offset is added to the output point:

```
p --> R*p + t
  ( = T*R*p )
```

So the final point is:

```
p' = R*p - t + t = R*p
 ( = T*inv(T)*R )
```

The translation matrix and its inverse (offset by `-t`) cancel each other out, and you are left with an effective rotation about the origin.

On the other hand, *post-multiplying* by the translation matrix is equivalent to pre-applying the translation:

```
p --> R*(p - t)
  ( = R*inv(T)*p )
```

So the correct final point is:

```
p' = R*(p - t) + t
 ( = T*R*inv(T)*p )
```

Note that the effective offset does not cancel out because `T` and `inv(T)` are not next to each other in the expression.

---

*Correct code*

```
model_final = tempModel1 * model * tempModel2;
            //    T      *   R   *   inv(T)
```

(Or using whichever one of your library's functions that multiplies the matrices in the "conventional" way as above)

Comment: I'm trying this but after the matrix multiplication I get the same value on almost every parameter of the matrix from columns 1 to 3 -1.07374e+08 and on cloumn 4 3 I get 3.47176e+09. I'm gonna try make the multiplication myself.

Comment: @Aether I'm convinced that the math is correct, so it could be the library functions. Don't directly modify the matrix elements. Also check that the construction / modifier functions initialize all of the elements correctly - such high values tend to be uninitialized variables.

Comment: yeah, I'm already using diferent matrices for each step of the multiplication. Gonna do the math myself and see what I get

Comment: @meogoesthedog Got it working for some reason model_final = temp1 * model * temp2; didnt work, did model_final = temp1 * model; then model_final = model_final * temp2; and it worked fine

Comment: @Aether strange. Could be a problem with your multiplication operator overload. But nice that you got it to work.

Comment: Yeah, I'm gonna try to solve the operator thingy, thanks!

Comment: @mewogoesthedog Just a little thing I would like to point out, notice that if the rotation = 0 then it would be multiplied by cero, so its recommended that first you check the value of the rotation variable.

Comment: @Aether not sure what you mean by that. If the rotation angle is zero then the rotation matrix should be the **identity**, not zero.